# Join two tables and count nulls

Tags: sql, oracle, business-intelligence

I have two tables “Representation” and “Availability”.

Table Representation

```
Id_Rep Column A Column B
1            A                B 
.             .                 . 
.             .                 .
N           X               Y
```

Table availability

```
Id_Rep Column A Column B
1            A                B 
.             .                 . 
.             .                 .
N           X               Y
```

We store in the first table all the info of a representative and in the second all the representatives that are available. The second updates itself as the reps are validated.

I’m trying to make a query to insert into another table. Something like this mis

```
Id_Rep Column A Column B Available
1            A                B             1
2            A                B             0
.             .                 .              .
N           X               Y             N
```

This so I can know all the reps available but at the same time I want to know the ones that have been validated (the ones with the one)

I was thinking of joining the two tables and when the join is null I put the 0 and if it is not null I put the 1 but i can’t get the query right I will be very grateful I you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: Could you provide some really sample data and expect result?

Comment: Sample table definitions and SQL would help a lot. I don't understand your examples. In general you can either use a `case` expression, or else `count(*) - count(nullable_column)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.*,
       case when a.Id_Rep is null then 0 else 1 end as Available
from Representation r
left outer join Availability a
on r.Id_Rep  = a.Id_Rep
```